# Running App Engine for Free without Enabling Billing

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google App Engine is stopping Python 2 support in half month. Already a week ago deployment through `appcfg.py` was denied (server responds with error and rolls back deployment) (**Update** thanks, [solution found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64019706/941531)).

Python 2 environment as I far as I know was the only way for truly free (up to daily quota) running of App Engine. It didn't need even enabling billing (and providing credit card).

For Python 3 there is a `standard` environment which can be run for free as Google says, but when I tried to deploy it I was asked to enable `Cloud Build`, which in turn has free daily quota but needs enabling billing with providing credit card. Also I expect that standard environment has other features with free quota but compulsory billing enabled.

The drawback of billing enabled is that you don't get guarantee that you're not charged any money. If you have over-quota you'll be charged. Is there any easy method of forcing not to charge even 1 cent in monthly bills? There are some manual quota limiting methods, but need going through dozens of resources in each single small app-service and manually setting the limit, also with these methods you still may be charged small amount.

Are there easy current methods for having totally free applications with google-app-engine?

Also are there any other totally free (up to quota) popular platforms for running Python web applications? Same like app-engine.

Comment: App Engine is not stopping Python 2 support in a half month, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/long-term-support#python27 and https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/python2-sunset

Comment: @DustinIngram I'm saying about stopping based on my deployment experience. For Python 2 the only way to deploy apps was using tool `appcfg.py`, not only deployment but everything was done using it (including running local deployment server). But a week ago when deploying Google started to respond with message that `appcfg.py` is not supported anymore, and deployment finishes with error and rolls back, so there is no way to deploy Python 2, I think that is enough to say that Python 2 is not supported anymore.

Comment: Maybe Google moved away from `appcfg.py` to `gcloud` deployment for Python 2. I tried `gcloud` tool to deploy and it complains that it needs to enable billing for deployment, for Cloud Build support. Before that `appcfg.py` and Python 2 instances were totally free, not even billing enabling was needed. Now if they continue with Python 2 they requiring compulsory billing enabled, which wasn't needed before. Maybe this is the case, I don't know. Also maybe they started to charge money for Python 2 when over quota, before they were just stopping serving until end of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when appcfg deploy fails with error, the code is deployed, but the deployed version is not serving. you can follow deploy with set version to make it serving. use these 2 commands to deploy without billing account. 2nd one fixes the part that 1st one failed.

> appcfg.py update app.yaml

> appcfg.py set_default_version .

Comment: Wow! Thanks. It worked for me. You saved all my old app engine services, otherwise all of them had to die!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, although it doesn't fully answer my question regarding if there is a current easy way of having totally free applications, though this answer is the closest one to my need and in fact solves my main problem! Thanks! Would be also nice to know if there is some totally free (without even credit card) possibility of running `Python 3` too.

Comment: Does this still work? Used to work before but I tried this recently and my app now gives 500 error

Answer (score 5):

While I cannot know what your data usage will be (you can be charged for reads, writes, and storage, if they exceed the quota), there is a way to avoid being charged for instances, which is where most exceed the quota.  Make sure you set up your `app.yaml` to stay within the free tier:

```
runtime: python38
instance_class: F1 
automatic_scaling:  
  max_instances: 1
```

The `F1` will give you 28 instance hours per day, which is more than 24.  `max-instances` will avoid spinning up new instances.

More at:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements

Also, you can go to:

https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/, then go to your billing account's "Budgets and alerts" section (icon in left pane), and set a budget to $0.  You may have to set the budget to a positive number to get the alerts to trigger at a % of that number (eg: 10% of $0.01).  Per the docs:

> Tip: Setting a budget does not automatically cap Google Cloud or
> Google Maps Platform usage/spending. Budgets trigger alerts to inform
> you of how your usage costs are trending over time. Budget alert
> emails might prompt you to take action to control your costs, but do
> not automatically prevent the use or billing of your services when the
> budget amount or threshold rules are met or exceeded.

You may have to set up a pub/sub or similar to receive the notification and shut down the app.

Comment: I'm afraid that over-quota may be for any kind of resource. So not to have unexpected bills I would like to have one-shot way to cutoff all resources at their free quota limit. But thanks for your solution for instance-limiting quota. Basically I'm very surprised that Google didn't provide single check-box e.g. `Totally Free` that will stop all resources when reaching quota. More than that they didn't provide an easy way of limiting all resources, you need to go through dozens of resources for each small service and manually set limit there. Great if there is script for automating this.

Comment: Do you know if limits for all resources can be controlled from `app.yaml`? Is there somewhere a list of these options with description? It would be a great solution, because I can just copy once-made yaml file to all dozen of small apps-services. It is much easier than going manually through graphical web UI and setting quotas.

Comment: Nope.  It's up to you to limit your reads, writes, database size, and storage to stay within the free quota.

Comment: How can I limit my resource usage when application is exposed to public. One day there might be a user that will issue million of queries per day that will result in huge over-quota. At least if I have to limit my resources I expect that there should be some easy tool or setting to limit those resources. I'm very surprised that Google didn't do a single check box like `Force 0$ Bill for this App` or `All Apps`, I expect many users will want to have only free open source applications even within limited quota.

Comment: As far as I know budgets don't limit anything, they just alert. It means if there is a DDOS attack on service at night and budget alerts me via e-mail also at night, still in the morning when I wake up and able to take action there might be already a bill of 200$. I want something that takes action, e.g. stops my services if they over quota.

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned at the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#billing_verification):

Google asks for a credit card or other payment method when you sign up for the Free Trial. Google uses this payment information for the following purposes:

- To verify your identity.
- To distinguish actual people from robots.

On the other hand, if you want to keep the free tier you need to meet the following [criteria](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier):

- You do not have a custom contract or rate card with Google.
- You are actively in the Free Trial period or you have upgraded to a
  paid account by enabling billing.
- Your account is in good standing.

You can take a look at the official usage limits [here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits), this information will help you to set limits on your app.yaml file in order to don't exceed the limits of your instance.

To be able to better control the resources used in your project, you can implement a [budget alert](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets), keep in mind that the management of resources as well as the implementation of good practices in your project is the responsibility of the user.

Also, if you want to have more control on your resources you can use the cap billing to stop usage service on the [budget alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage).

Finally, if you think there has been an error in the charges to your project as long as you meet the requirements, you can go to the support offered by [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues#unrecognized-charges)

Comment: The question was more about "how to stay free with 100% guarantee". With that Free Tier that you are mentioning is there a 100% guarantee that you're not charged? If you're over daily quota what happens? Services are forcefully stopped? Or you are charged?

Comment: I've just read in the above documentation you linked this message `Any usage above Free Tier usage limits is automatically billed at standard rates.` So Free Tier doesn't guarantee real freedom.

Comment: To stay at the level of the free tier, you do not need to exceed the limits indicated in the documentation and meet the requirements indicated to be eligible, it is the user's responsibility to manage their own resources

Comment: And I want to know what is the way to stay `free`, i.e. what is the guaranteed way to cut off resources at free limit. For example to check box somewhere that I want all of my services to forcefully being stopped if I they exceed 90% of any type of free limits. As far as I was reading there were no easy way to do that. My concern is that if I leave my services running overnight and go to sleep, I may wake up and see 100$ bill, because of some random user's DOS attack at them, or other way of over-usage.

Comment: BTW, thanks for your answer. Do I understand correctly that after stopping of `Python 2` support there is no way at all to run apps without providing credit card? (even just for identification)

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, it is necessary to have a credit card associated with the project for security reasons.

Comment: Budget alert just alerts you with e-mail. It doesn't stop your instances or deletes resources. So you may be alerted by e-mail at night and have 100$ bill in the morning.

Comment: I'm seeking if there is some check box like `stop everything if over 90% of any quota`. Also as I'm having many small services I need some easy way to say that for all my services, not to go through all of them manually.

Comment: So as I see there is no really easy way of achieving `free`-dom, or at least we didn't find an easy one. So I must accept your solution as the closest one.